# Custom File Palette

Tags: palettes

I find the default Mathematica IDE lacking.  I am missing a simple project file tree on the left (as in eclipse, visual studio etc.)

The following would be very cool:

All your files (in a given directory) would be displayed in a Mathematica Palette. Clicking them changes to the clicked file or opens it.

Has anyone seen something like this?
Can anyone put together a quick proof of concept?
It should not be that difficult ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

as J.M. mentions, the [Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) is an Eclipse plug-in (and is available as such).

Now, to display all files in some directory, you can do this:

```
SetDirectory["~/Documents/Projects/other/playing"]
```

(this is an arbitrarily selected directory on my machine). Then define

```
doSomething[fname_] := CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[
   {
    TextCell[fname],
    Button["open", NotebookOpen[fname]],
    Button["beep", Beep[]],
    DefaultButton[]
    }
   ]
  ]
```

(this will take as an argument the file name and pop up a dialog asking what to do; I've put in placeholder actions here). Then

```
Grid[Partition[#, 2] &[
  Button[#, doSomething[ToFileName[Directory[], #]]] & /@ 
   FileNames[]]]
```

gives something like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and clicking on the names brings this up:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course this can be greatly elaborated.

Comment: Nice. Perhaps `FileNames["*.nb"]` to avoid DS_Store and PDF opening...

Comment: @cormullion you're right, if you want only nb and m files to appear. originally this was part of a palette I have where each file is treated differently according to extension (basically a way for me to avoid having to leave mathematica to manage my output files etc)