# How to efficiently read data from any part inside huge file

Tags: data

I have a data file (over 2.5  GB) and I want to do calculations on the data.

At first I used.

```
data=ReadList["file", Record,n]
```

I still have three problems:

1- From the Doc of `ReadList` (`ReadList["file",types,n]` reads only the first n objects of the specified types) reading starts from the beginning of the file. ***So how can I read from any part inside the file*** ( It is clear if I use `n` the last record, this means I am reading the whole file which I can't).

2- If there is way to read from any part of the file and let us say I want to read the last 1000 objects, how can I know `n` (last object of the file).

3- The data (after reading) is in this form:

```
   {" 0.00000E+000\t-9.15527E-004\t", " 2.50000E-006\t-0.0015258789\t", \
    " 5.00000E-006\t-0.0018310547\t", " 7.50000E-006\t-0.0015258789\t"}
```

I want to create two columns of the data. I used this way:

```
Interpreter["Number"][ReadList[StringToStream[#], Word] & /@ data]
```

As can be seen, I used `ReadList` twice (one at first reading and one to convert the data).
Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar: [Get the last line from each of a large number of files ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55536/142).

Comment: `Skip` may be useful here.