# What is the fastest way to read the new lines in the dynamically updatable file?

Tags: import, streams

I'm writing a log to a simple .txt file and want to read the last few records using Mathematica. But there are some problems.

[image]

```
f = OpenRead["logs.txt"];

Skip[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2], 1];

Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
```

> {3, 4}

Add lines and save.

[image]

```
Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
```

> EndOfFile

Of course, I can closing file every time, open again, to do `Skip` and read updated data. But this is very slow for the large log file.

It should be noted that all lines in my log are aligned to have the specific size. In this example they have size 7 bytes. So I can check the number of records:

```
FileByteCount["logs.txt"]/7
```

> 4

**ADDENDUM**

`SetStreamPosition` is fast. But first run is slower than consequent. For example, on the real data:

```
f = OpenRead["all_trades.txt"];

(* first run *)
SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
SetStreamPosition[f, 3899999]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.02188, Null} *)

(* second run *)
SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
SetStreamPosition[f, 3899999]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.000301056, Null}

SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
Skip[f, ConstantArray[Number, 10], 100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.162914, Null} *)

StreamPosition[f]
(* 3899999 *)

Close[f];
```

**But this does not work with updatable data!**

[image]

```
f = OpenRead["logs.txt"];

Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
(* {1, 2} *)

StreamPosition[f]
(* 5 *)

SetStreamPosition[f, 6];
Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
(* {3, 4} *)

StreamPosition[f]
(* 11 *)
```

Add lines and save.

[image]

```
SetStreamPosition[f, 12];
Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
(* EndOfFile *)
```

**It looks like a bug. Is not it?**

There are no problems in Python.

```
f = open('logs.txt', 'r')

# Add lines and save.
f.seek(14)
f.read(2)
```

> '05'

Comment: I don't think C or C++ streams dynamically update to accommodate live-action file changes (not an answer, and of questionable relevancy, but perhaps worth noting)

Comment: The file's initial data is likely sent to some sort of buffer as soon as the stream is opened. The buffer won't dynamically update, as the data's already been sent. I would be surprised if this were considered a bug, but who knows.

Comment: @user6014 You're right - this is not a bug. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Wolfram Support Answer**

> The input stream is "buffered" by C, which is to say the file's data is read into memory when the stream is opened. Then all "read" operations work on the buffered data in memory, so if the file changes in the meantime, those changes are not reflected. This is a lot faster than constantly checking the file on disk.
>
> You could remember the current stream position (using StreamPosition), Close the file, re-open the file again (using OpenRead), and then move back to the saved stream position (using SetStreamPosition). Closing and re-opening would get rid of the in-memory buffer.
>
> This is, of course, not dynamic and unfortunately, there is not a documented or supported method of doing this.
>
> **However, OpenRead with the option AppendCheck->True may be able to fill the purpose**. The option will reset the end of file marker in most cases allowing new information from the file to be read. This option is not documented or supported, so please consider this when using it at your discretion as we would not be able to provide further information on it.

**Benchmarking**

```
f = OpenRead["all_trades.txt", AppendCheck -> True];
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
 Skip[f, ConstantArray[Number, 10], 163658];
 ]
```

> {0.246617, Null}

```
StreamPosition[f]
```

> 6382661

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
 SetStreamPosition[f, 6382661];
 ]
```

> {0.00020363, Null}

Add a new line to the file and save.

```
Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 10]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000380343, Null}

So `OpenRead[..., AppendCheck -> True]` is the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

This might be OS-dependent, but I would assume that:

```
oldPos = StreamPosition[f];
Close[f];
f = OpenRead["f:\\imgs\\logs.txt"];
SetStreamPosition[f, p];
Read[f, ConstantArray[Number, 2]]
```

should be faster than `Skip`, since it just moves the low-level file pointer.

Comment: Good (+1). But it does not work. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Hm, it looks as if you're using `SetStreamPosition` wrong. Generally, with text files you should assume that only positions returned by `StreamPosition` are valid. For example, if the file is unicode-encoded, you might seek to a position "in the middle" of a character, and you will only read garbage from then on. I'm not sure why it isn't working, though. If you close the file, re-open it and seek to the previous position, you should see the new data?

Comment: Yes, I see the new data when close and re-open the file. First run of `SetStreamPosition` is 7x faster than `Skip`. But second run of `SetStreamPosition` is yet more faster than the first (73x relative to the first run or 543x relative to `Skip`). When I close file, first run of `SetStreamPosition` will be again slower that the second, even in the same kernel session. Also there are small overheads on closing and re-opening the file. The ideal solution would be to avoid closing the file as in Python.

Comment: Can you reproduce `EndOfFile` error with my example? I am thinking whether should I report this case to the developers.

Comment: And yes, I can read file in Python directly from Mathematica using `ExternalEvaluate` ;-)

Comment: The second call to `SetStreamPosition` is probably faster because the portion of the file is already cached in memory. That's also why you don't see new data. Which bug do you mean?

Comment: Bug: I can not read the new data in the file and get an error `EndOfFile`.

Comment: If you put the stream position to a place that wasn't returned from `StreamPosition` previously, the results are probably undefined - depending on the file contents, encoding and OS, anything can happen. I don't think that's a bug.